# PyQt Thread Completes and outputs same message twice

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, threadpool

I'm trying to create a play/pause/resume/ button with a progress bar. User presses 'Start' and the progress bar initializes and a pause/resume button populates. Once the progress completes, a message is printed and the pause/resume buttons are hidden while the 'Start' button is shown again. However, when I try to run 'Start' again, it prints the same completion message an additional time.

If I run it twice, it prints out two completion messages. Run it three times, prints out three completion messages and etc.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
        QWidget, QApplication, QProgressBar, QMainWindow,
        QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
    )
    
from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QRunnable, QThreadPool
)
import time


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = pyqtSignal()

class JobRunner(QRunnable):
    
    signals = WorkerSignals()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.is_paused = False
        self.is_killed = False
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        for n in range(100):
            self.signals.progress.emit(n + 1)
            time.sleep(0.001)
            
            while self.is_paused:
                time.sleep(0)
                
            if self.is_killed:
                break
        self.signals.finished.emit()


    def finished(self):
        print('Finished')
                
    def pause(self):
        self.is_paused = True
        
    def resume(self):
        self.is_paused = False
        
    # def kill(self):


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Some buttons
        self.w = QWidget()
        self.l = QHBoxLayout()
        self.w.setLayout(self.l)
        
        self.btn_start = QPushButton("Start")

        
        self.l.addWidget(self.btn_start)

        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.w)
       
        # Create a statusbar.
        self.status = self.statusBar()
        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        self.status.addPermanentWidget(self.progress)
        
        # Thread runner
        # self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        
        # # Create a runner
        # self.runner = JobRunner()
        # self.runner.signals.progress.connect(self.update_progress)
        # self.threadpool.start(self.runner)

        self.btn_start.pressed.connect(self.start_runner)
        # btn_pause.pressed.connect(self.runner.pause)
        # btn_resume.pressed.connect(self.runner.resume)
        

        # self.startTestSignal.connect(self.update_progress)

        self.show()
    
    def update_progress(self, n):
        self.progress.setValue(n)

    def start_runner(self):
        # Create ThreadPool
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.threadpool.clear()
        # Create a runner
        self.runner = JobRunner()
        self.runner.signals.progress.connect(self.update_progress)

        self.threadpool.start(self.runner)
        self.progress.setValue(0)


        # Change Start Button to Pause
        self.btn_start.hide()

        # self.btn_start.setEnabled(False)

        self.btn_pause = QPushButton("Pause")
        self.btn_resume = QPushButton("Resume")
        self.l.addWidget(self.btn_pause)
        self.l.addWidget(self.btn_resume)

        self.btn_pause.pressed.connect(self.runner.pause)
        self.btn_resume.pressed.connect(self.runner.resume)
        self.runner.signals.finished.connect(self.check)


    def check(self):
        print('Thread Done')
        self.btn_start.show()
        self.progress.setValue(0)

        # self.runner.terminate()
        self.btn_pause.hide()
        self.btn_resume.hide()
        




        
app = QApplication([])
w = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `WorkerSignals` as a *class* attribute, making it a persistent for the *class*; so when you do this:

```
    self.runner.signals.finished.connect(self.check)
```

you are actually connecting *again* to `signals.finished`, and when you emit the signal the function `self.check` is called each time the signal has been connected.

The solution is to create the `WorkerSignals` as an *instance* attribute:

```
class JobRunner(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        self.is_paused = False
        self.is_killed = False
```